# IE8 CSS rotation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, rotation

I'm looking for CSS solution for rotating elements in IE8. Some of solutions I've found say that it should work in IE8, but it does not for me. What I do wrong?

Here is what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .rotate {
            font-weight: bold;color: #000;background: #aa0;display: block;margin: 0 auto;width: 300px;height: 300px;top: 10%;text-align: center;line-height: 300px;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="rotate">
    TESTING ROTATION
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate if you test your solution before answering, and it would be great ir you could just edit my given example and repost all code.

**[EDIT]**
If anyone is still curious the problem is not the code, but the testing environment.
You should use real IE8, but not IE8 emulator in IE10/IE11 (not sure about IE9)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie

Answer (score 7):

You are missing IE vendor prefix -ms-

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

So, Use this

```
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); /* for IE8 */
```

Also look at this question: [CSS rotate property in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie) that might help you

Comment: Does it work for you? Could you give me full HTML code like my example? Because it won't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Well,  I dont think the filters for rotation work in a elegant way in IE8. I also tried that, but it didnt work for me properly. I tried using jquery rotate plugin. You can try that out - http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

I have a issue even with that going on ([jQueryRotate - Issue in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165143/jqueryrotate-issue-in-ie8/19165721?noredirect=1#19165721)), but it might help you, just in case.